# C# WPF Toolkit DataGrid - Group inside Group?

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid, toolkit

I have a group which have items inside it and I would like that group to have a subgroup.

**Main groups**: "Windows", "Linux", "Mac" and **sub-groups**: "Data", "Basic", "Advanced"

The sub-groups will be the ones that will contain the row items. Also, there can be different sub-groups for each main group.

How can I do that?

Here's some of my code:

```
<Window.Resources>
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="OSGroups">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="os"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>

    <Style x:Key="GroupContainerStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Style.Resources>
            <LinearGradientBrush x:Key="OutBrush" StartPoint="0,0" EndPoint="0,1">
                <GradientStop Offset="0" Color="#FEB74B"/>
                <GradientStop Offset="1" Color="#F19201"/>
            </LinearGradientBrush>
        </Style.Resources>
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True" Background="{StaticResource OutBrush}" BorderThickness="0">
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <Grid>
                                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                                    <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
                                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

                                <StackPanel Grid.Column="0" Orientation="Horizontal" Margin="0,0,10,0">
                                    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Name}"/>
                                </StackPanel>
                            </Grid>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <wpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="CommandsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OSGroups}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" HeadersVisibility="Column" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
        <wpfToolkit:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
            <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupContainerStyle}">
                <GroupStyle.Panel>
                    <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                        <wpfToolkit:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                    </ItemsPanelTemplate>
                </GroupStyle.Panel>
            </GroupStyle>
        </wpfToolkit:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <wpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
            <wpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Command" Binding="{Binding Path=command}" />
            <wpfToolkit:DataGridTextColumn Header="Description" Width="*" Binding="{Binding Path=description}" />
        </wpfToolkit:DataGrid.Columns>
    </wpfToolkit:DataGrid>
</Grid>
```

Answer (score 1):

Note, the indentation only works with one sub group, since we only have "IsBottomLevel" and not "Level".

```
    <CollectionViewSource x:Key="OSGroups">
        <CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="os"/>
            <PropertyGroupDescription PropertyName="subGroup"/>
        </CollectionViewSource.GroupDescriptions>
    </CollectionViewSource>
    <Style x:Key="GroupHeaderStyle" TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
        <Setter Property="Template">
            <Setter.Value>
                <ControlTemplate TargetType="{x:Type GroupItem}">
                    <Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <Expander.Style>
                            <Style TargetType="{x:Type Expander}">
                                <Style.Triggers>
                                    <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding IsBottomLevel}" Value="True">
                                        <Setter Property="Margin" Value="20,0,0,0" />
                                    </DataTrigger>

                                </Style.Triggers>
                            </Style>
                        </Expander.Style>
                        <Expander.Header>
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Name}"/>
                        </Expander.Header>
                        <ItemsPresenter Margin="-10,0,0,0" />
                    </Expander>
                </ControlTemplate>
            </Setter.Value>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can define any no of styles inside `DataGrid.GroupStyle` element. Consider the below xaml, here I have defined two group container styles namely `GroupContainerStyle` and `SecondGroupContainerStyle`. Now for the main group(1st level) `GroupConstainerStyle` will be applied and for your subgroups(2nd level) `SecondGroupContainerStyle` will be applied automatically.

In `SecondGroupContainerStyle` you could change the indentation like how spasrto has done.

```
<wpfToolkit:DataGrid Name="CommandsDataGrid" AutoGenerateColumns="False" IsReadOnly="True" CanUserAddRows="False" CanUserDeleteRows="False" CanUserResizeRows="False" CanUserSortColumns="False" ItemsSource="{Binding Source={StaticResource OSGroups}}" CellStyle="{StaticResource CellStyle}" HeadersVisibility="Column" Height="250" HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" VerticalAlignment="Stretch">
    <wpfToolkit:DataGrid.GroupStyle>
        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource GroupContainerStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <wpfToolkit:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>

        <GroupStyle ContainerStyle="{StaticResource SecondGroupContainerStyle}">
            <GroupStyle.Panel>
                <ItemsPanelTemplate>
                    <wpfToolkit:DataGridRowsPresenter/>
                </ItemsPanelTemplate>
            </GroupStyle.Panel>
        </GroupStyle>           
    </wpfToolkit:DataGrid.GroupStyle>

</wpfToolkit:DataGrid>
```